# SQL Server 2012 - Gerar consulta de uma tabela para outra envolvendo 3 (três) tabelas de uma só vez

Tags: sql-server-2012

Olá, Comunidade!

Eu preciso de ajuda com a **lógica** de uma consulta que eu tenho que fazer no *SQL Server 2012*.

Bem, eu tenho três tabelas: [1'] `operacao_apf`; [2] `operacao_contrato`; e, [3] `operacao_detalhe`.

O que eu preciso fazer: em [1'], preciso pegar o nome de uma operação qualquer, e, pelo nome, tenho que ir em [2] e selecionar todos os contratos relacionados a esta operação. Depois de selecionados todos os contratos em [2] relacionados à operação pesquisada em [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGOcf.png), eu preciso ir em [3] e selecionar todos os detalhes relacionados a cada contrato de [2] relacionado a operação em [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGOcf.png).

Esquema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que as tabelas estão associadas sempre de `1:N` da esquerda para a direita. Uma operação pode ter vários contratos e cada contrato pode ter vários detalhes.

O que eu quero fazer é gerar um relatório com isso, mas preciso enteder a lógica do SQL Server 2012 para poder começar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User o [INNER JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177634.aspx) do sql.

Especifica todos os pares de linhas correspondentes retornados. Descarta as linhas não correspondentes de ambas as tabelas. Quando nenhum tipo de junção é especificado, este é o padrão.

FULL [ OUTER ]
Especifica que uma linha da tabela esquerda ou direita que não atende à condição de junção seja incluída no conjunto de resultados, e as colunas de saída correspondentes à outra tabela sejam definidas como NULL. Isso ocorre além de todas as linhas normalmente retornadas por INNER JOIN.

LEFT [ OUTER ]
Especifica que todas as linhas da tabela esquerda que não atendem à condição de junção sejam incluídas no conjunto de resultados, e as colunas de saída da outra tabela sejam definidas como NULL além de todas as linhas retornadas pela junção interna.
RIGHT [OUTER]
Especifica que todas as linhas da tabela direita que não atendem à condição de junção sejam incluídas no conjunto de resultados, e as colunas de saída que correspondem à outra tabela sejam definidas como NULL, além de todas as linhas retornadas pela junção interna.

Especifica que o otimizador de consultas do SQL Server use uma dica de junção, ou um algoritmo de execução, para cada consulta especificada na cláusula FROM da consulta. Para obter mais informações, consulte dicas de junção (Transact-SQL).
JOIN
Indica que a operação de junção especificada deve acontecer entre as origens de tabela ou exibições especificadas.

ON 
Especifica o critério no qual a junção se baseia. Os critérios podem especificar qualquer predicado, embora colunas e operadores de comparação sejam frequentemente usados, por exemplo:

```
SELECT *  
FROM operacao_apf AS o   
JOIN operacao_contrato AS c  
ON o.ProductID = c.ProductID -- altere com os ids derelação  
JOIN operacao_detalhe AS d  
ON c.ProductID = d.ProductID -- altere com os ids derelação
```

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado! Deu certo!